# Hadoop hanging on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, ubuntu-14.04

I'm setting up Hadoop 0.20.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 using JAVA SDK 6. I've been following the instructions at http://arifn.web.id/blog/2010/07/29/running-hadoop-single-cluster.html and have gotten as far as "Formatting and Running Hadoop." As instructed, I enter

```
bin/hadoop namenode-format
bin/hadoop start-all.sh
```

This seems to work, and I'm able to view the status of my nodes with

```
bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

Next, I stop all my nodes with

```
bin/stop-all.sh
```

At this point, I get an error, and Hadoop stops responding to any commands. Instead, it just hangs, and doesn't give any feedback. I've tried reformatting the namenode and starting the scripts again with

```
bin/hadoop namenode-format
bin/hadoop start-all.sh
```

...but I'm still getting the same problem where Hadoop hangs any time I ask it to do anything. I'm not getting any error messages, or really any feedback at all: as soon as I hit Enter (even on something as simple as bin/hadoop), it just hangs.

I've actually tried installing Hadoop twice on Ubuntu and I've encountered this problem both times. Does anyone have any ideas on why this might be happening or advice on how it can be solved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Formatting namenode use the following command, a space needed between namenode and -format option

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

For starting hadoop daemons use the following command(removed hadoop)

```
bin/start-all.sh
```

Once hadoop deamons are started, Use either `jps` or `ps aux | grep -i hadoop` commands to ensure hadoop daemons are running,

Comment: Should he use Yarn as well?

Comment: In the question hadoop version is 0.20.2, yarn is not available in this version !!

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs in your deployment. It should be int the logs directoryin the Hadoop home directory by default.